# Im having trouble concatenating a string with an int

Tags: arduino

I have the below code to read a light sensor, convert to lux, concat with "lux." and send it to my SmartThings cloud. 
Ultimately I want a value sent to SmartThings formatted like `lux.110`

```
void checkLux() { 
  float logLux = analogRead(lightPIN) * logRange / rawRange;
  int luxValue = pow(10, logLux); 
  String statusUpdate = "lux." + luxValue; 
  Serial.println(statusUpdate);
  smartthing.send(statusUpdate); 
  delay(1000);
}
```

This above code spits out some weird combination of characters to the serial monitor and doesnt print lux. or the luxvalue. 
If I add this line `String luxString = "lux.";` and modify the line below, it all works great. Any thoughts on why I need to declare this string separately. According to the documentation either should work fine.

Also if there are any suggestions on variable savings within this block of code. I am not that great at it yet.

Comment: You can use concat function. `statusUpdate.concat(luxValue)` Doesnt that solve your problem?

Comment: @ahaltindis That's an answer, put it in the answers section.

Answer (score 3):

As Arduino just uses C++ most C++ functions will also work so dont just limit yourself to [Arduino's reference pages](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage).
Apparently the String constructor doesn't support numbers, you must convert them using the String() function first as seen [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors).
Alternatively I think you can append a string like this:

```
String statusUpdate = "lux.";
statusUpdate += luxValue;
```

as seen [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAppendOperator),
which is the same as using String's concat function.

```
statusUpdate.concat(luxValue);
```